# How to get all mouse buttons that are held down in LibGDX?

Tags: java, input, libgdx, mouse

I would like to loop through all the mouse buttons that are currently pressed in so I can implement a per-button dragging system. Is there a way to do that in LibGDX ?

Example use case:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)
{
    Vector3 prev = obtain(Vector3.class);
    Vector3 cur = obtain(Vector3.class);

    prev.set(dragX, dragY, 0);
    cur.set(screenX, screenY, 0);

    screen.getCamera().unproject(prev); //unprojecting previous position
    screen.getCamera().unproject(cur); //unprojecting current position

    for(int button : getPressedButtons())
    {
        drag((int)cur.x, (int)cur.y, (int)(cur.x - prev.x), (int)(cur.y - prev.y), button); //calling my own drag method that support mouse buttons
    }

    free(prev);
    free(cur);
    dragX = screenX;
    dragY = screenY;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `isButtonPressed()` on Gdx.input. If you want to avoid boxing and array allocations, you'll have to iterate the long-winded way:

```
private final IntSet pressedButtons = new IntSet(5); 
// There are five possible buttons (See com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Buttons)

void updatePressedButtons (){
    pressedButtons.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(i)) pressedButtons.add(i);
}
```

.

```
IntSetIterator iterator = pressedButtons.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext){
    drag((int)cur.x, (int)cur.y, (int)(cur.x - prev.x), (int)(cur.y - prev.y), iterator.next());
}
```

(or use Java 8's PrimitiveIterator)